# Can I install packages from the node_modules directory?

Tags: node.js, npm

So a friend has sent me his node_modules directory but I don't want to manually type `npm i *package*` for each package and I don't have the package.json file to npm install from.

Is there a possible way to install the packages in the node_modules directory via terminal?

It is a very backwards scenario, I'm just curious if there's a way...

Comment: Well, just replace your node_modules folder with the one from your friend. That way you have all the dependencies. If you're interested in generating a package.json from that folder, unfortunately that's not possible. You could [shrinkwrap](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/shrinkwrap) it tho.

Comment: You can ask your friend to send the package.json file. I mean he's your friend why would he refuse to send that.

Comment: @Ramesh yeah he sent it, I was just curious whilst he was afk if I could generate it before he replied!

Answer (score 0):

You can running:

```
npm ls -json > tree.json
node -e "console.log(Object.entries(require('./tree.json').dependencies).map(([m, v])=>m+'@'+v.version))"
```

It will print

> [ 'fastify@2.13.0', 'fastify-url-data@2.4.0', 'pino-pretty@3.6.1' ]

for my test

Comment: Unfortunately, this only works for the packages already listed in package.json

Comment: Could you elaborate?
I installed an app, removed package and lock, then run those script